Generating grid from polyline feature
I'd like to create a polygon grid based on polyline features, but I'm not sure which geoprocessing tools I need to use.
In the attached image I selected 3 different groups of polylines (each group has 3,4 linear segments that has a common ID) that I'd like to draw a polygon shape around. The yellow outline is what I'm trying to draw or automate.
The goal is to crate a map series and use each polygon to zoom in to the area of interest.
The polygons I'm planning to generating will all be different shapes and sizes.
I was looking into tools such as "Grid Index Features" and "Fishnet", but they generate grids base on a set unit size. Is there a tool that generate grid based on another feature class?
I'm using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.3


Instead of creating a polygon feature class from your polylines you can just use your polyline feature class directly as your map series index layer.
From Create a spatial map series:

A spatial map series generates a set of output pages by taking a
single layout and iterating over a set of map extents. The extents are
defined by the features in a layer known as the index layer.

A polyline feature class can serve as the index layer.
